# Laptop brightness resets on opening lid?

Tags: backlight

So I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop(fresh install) and am having an issue I did not have in Ubuntu 15.10. So I have set the *When the lid is closed* to *Do Nothing* as I don't want my laptop to suspend or hibernate when I close the lid. I generally set the brightness to the lowest possible level, and unlike previous versions, the brightness does not reset on every reboot. But when I close and open the lid, the brightness resets to maximum. Is there any way to solve this?